# Can we have the window title for a question start with the question?

Tags: feature-request

The title attribute in the page of a question like [Comparison between $E_2$-terms of Leray and “second hypercohomology” spectral sequences](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135480/comparison-between-e-2-terms-of-leray-and-second-hypercohomology-spectral-se) is currently set to "ag.algebraic geometry - Comparison between $E_2$-terms of Leray and “second hypercohomology” spectral sequences - MathOverflow" and I'd prefer if the title started with the question (it could still contain a tag after the question, or do away with the tag altogether). The reason is that my browser (like most, I think) has tabs and displays the title in the tab; with a few tabs open all I can see of each title is the tag, which is not very informative: I'd prefer to see the intial portion of the question.

EDIT: I followed [Kaveh](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/users/7507/kaveh)'s advice and am using the following simpleminded script (this is version 2, as the first one was too simpleminded):

```
document.title = document.title.replace(
  /^([^-]*) - (.*) - (MathOverflow)$/,
  "$2 - $3");
```

If you use, say, Firefox, with the [dotjs extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dotjs/), you can store that text in the file named `~/.js/mathoverflow.net.js` and it'll remove the tag from the question titles. (As you can see above it is a blunt tool, doing a simple pattern match to check to remove the stuff before the first " - ", if there is a second " - ".)

Comment: Seems like an excellent request! (Everyone should vote up feature requests they like, just in case that isn't obvious.)

Comment: Interestingly, on Meta the title starts with the question and doesn't include the tag.

Answer (score 3):

The page titles start with a tag [to help search engines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles/130208#130208). Because of how search engines work, to give these tags significance compared to other words in the question title they need to be the first thing in the page titles. This request has been brought up a number of times previously so I think it is unlikely to be accepted. See for example:

> [First tag in the title of the page is not that convenient](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71906/first-tag-in-the-title-of-the-page-is-not-that-convenient)

It seems to me it is much faster and easier to write a simple *user script* to get rid of the tags in the page titles on our own browsers than to try to change the whole system.

Comment: I would think that the words in the title are an infinitely more significant in locating a question than the tags, so even if this is supposed to be helping search engines find relevant things, it is sort of backwards...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, I am not an expert on the issue, you can read more from the links posted [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71950/153230). I think the easier way to solve the issue is probably using a _user script_ to remove the tags from the titles.

Comment: The tag in the title is essential for sites like SO and Arqade which often omit important keywords in the title and put them into a tag. But I don't think this is valid for all sites, and [I've asked for this to be changed on Skeptics a while back](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1273/5).

Comment: @MadScientist, I personally think topic classification is essential for most of other sites also. Let me add that [we have made a similar request 2 years ago on cstheory](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/861/title-text-tag-then-question-name). As long as the issue explained by Jeff continues it is unlikely that SE will change its position regarding these requests. It seems they cannot even change this for users who are logged in because of search engine rules.

Comment: I took your advice, @Kaveh, and wrote a tiny script. I added it in an edit to my question.

Comment: @Omar, nice :) btw, you can also use [Grease Monkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) addon if you use Firefox or [Tamper Monkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) if you use Chrome. There might be also some similar script on [userscripts.org](https://userscripts.org/).

Comment: Here is another one: https://userscripts.org/scripts/review/92973

Comment: @Kaveh, having the word «algebra» displayed in title windows is close to useless to us....

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, I agree.